# ffmpeg save remote file to user's computer

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I can cut and save a video from a remote server to my server using the below command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -i "example.com/test.mp4" -t 00:00:09 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -async 1 -y out.mp4
```

I was wondering if I could prompt the user for a permission to save it on his computer instead of downloading it to my server. I will be using php with the exec function.

Comment: you could but not if you want to do the cutting first. You could present it for download after you've processed it, though

Comment: You can provide the functionality to download the video from your server. If you have admin control over the users machine and ffmpeg is installed there, you could provision a mechanism to supply the command line from your server to be executed on the client (although this has the potential to open up lots of security holes).